# bind(): No such file or directory [core/socket.c line 230]

Tags: uwsgi, unix-socket

I'm trying to create a unix socket application for a run in uWSGI... but does not allow me to create the socket, please check the following settings.

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /home/deploy/webapps/domain/virtualenv/app
module          = app.wsgi
home            = /home/deploy/webapps/domain/virtualenv
master          = true
processes       = 10
uwsgi-socket    = /var/run/uwsgi/app/%n/socket # if i'm tried /tmp/name.socket if work!
vacuum          = true

# Error codes:
The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.
bind(): No such file or directory [core/socket.c line 230]
```

I have given permissions to this directory and is created but does not work.

```
mkdir -p /var/run/uwsgi/app
sudo chown -R deploy:root /var/run/uwsgi/app
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/uwsgi/app
```

which would be the same solution for this. thanks.

Comment: the directory is /var/run/uwsgi/app/%n not /var/run/uwsgi/app, %n is the name of the config file, so ensure this directory exists.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do two things:

```
mkdir /var/run/app-uwsgi
```

and

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/run/app-uwsgi
```

After a reboot this directory gets lost and needs to be recreated in Ubuntu.

Comment: This IS because of an incorrect directory, but the question here isn't running as www-data (based on the provided config), and has a different path that they are trying to put the socket in.

Comment: The first suggestion makes no sense and look to be a typing error. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error trying to run uwsgi inside a Docker container, so I needed to create the directories first.

I needed to add the following command to the end of my Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/todobackend
```

The settings of the server in my case are part of the docker-compose.yml file:

```
      - uwsgi
      - "--socket /var/www/todobackend/todobackend.sock"
      - "--chmod-socket=666"
      - "--module todobackend.wsgi"
      - "--master"
      - "--die-on-term"
```